# ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined when executing ng serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When trying to execute command `ng serve` on a new project, without code changes, an error occurred:

ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

this is the `ng --version` command output:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.1.4
Node: 14.2.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.4
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.4
@angular/cli                      9.1.4
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.4
@schematics/angular               9.1.4
@schematics/update                0.901.4
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

**EDIT:**
The complete error shown is:

```
ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined
    at resolveAlias (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:36513:37)
    at checkAliasSymbol (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64502:26)
    at checkImportBinding (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64534:13)
    at checkImportDeclaration (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64552:29)
    at checkSourceElementWorker (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64961:28)
    at checkSourceElement (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:64800:17)
    at Object.forEach (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:317:30)
    at checkSourceFileWorker (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65123:20)
    at checkSourceFile (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65091:13)
    at getDiagnosticsWorker (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65179:17)
    at Object.getDiagnostics (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:65165:24)
    at E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98703:85
    at runWithCancellationToken (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98665:24)
    at getBindAndCheckDiagnosticsForFileNoCache (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98691:20)
    at getAndCacheDiagnostics (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98956:26)
    at getBindAndCheckDiagnosticsForFile (E:\source\www\angular\test\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:98688:20)
```

**EDIT:**
I could solve the problem by reinstaling version 9.1.4 of angular inside the project, as @cklimowski suggested in his answer.

The command i used:

```
npm install @angular/core@9.1.4 @angular/animations@9.1.4 @angular/common@9.1.4 @angular/forms@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser@9.1.4 @angular/router@9.1.4 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@9.1.4 @angular/compiler@9.1.4 @angular/compiler-cli@9.1.4 @angular/language-service@9.1.4
```

Comment: could you add the error message and its stack trace?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36993

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with 9.1.5. Roll back or install 9.1.4 and you will be fine.

UPDATE:

9.1.6 is now working without this issue. Upgrade to the latest version of both CLI and Core.

Comment: Why is angular cli 9.1.4 using angular 9.1.5 instead of 9.1.4?

Comment: Not sure, seems to be an issue with 9.1.5. Doesn't normally happen, wait for 9.1.6. Keep both cli and core on 9.1.4 for now. And mark my answer as accepted if this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try to update all dependencies. For me it works, but I have different nodejs version.

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.1.4
Node: 12.16.3
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 9.1.5
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.4
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.4
@angular/cdk                      9.2.2
@angular/cli                      9.1.4
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.4
@schematics/angular               9.1.4
@schematics/update                0.901.4
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

Comment: I made a test with latest stable version of nodejs (12.16.3) but the error remains when creating a new project. The only thing that worked was what @cklimowski answered.

Comment: I see, then true, maybe an issue on windows due to different ways how to pass args and flags.

Answer (score 0):

these are generally the easiest bugs to fix. do a search of your code for '.flags'

somewhere you are attempting to access .flags of a variable that is undefined. for example: user.flags. you can make the error go away by adding a simple if statement:

```
if(user) {
    user.flags = 3 // or whatever
    //code failing goes here
}
```

Comment: I know what the error message mean. The error is in angular 9.1.5 itself or some of it's dependencies, not in my code. In fact, as i stated in my question, there is no code of mine, it's a new project created with angular cli 9.1.4.